# Getting duplicate records using SQLIte

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have a table called `Organization` which looks like so..

[Please see Organization table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfkM1.png)

I also have another table `Plant`with the same plantID that looks like so(in the image, Plant_Id is to the extreme right)..

[Please see Plant table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XRxK.png)

When I use inner join to get a specific row, I get the same row repeated twice. This is the query I used...

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  eSMAT_List INNER JOIN Organization on eSMAT_List.Plant_Id = 291320`

What am I doing wrong here..?

(Also, I have hardcoded 291320 because that is a value I wish to pass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You aren't actually `JOINING` your tables, you need to `JOIN` on a common key value in both tables. (From your pictures I'd say it's `Organization.mainID` and `eSMAT_List.Plant_Id`).
2. You want to use a `WHERE` clause to filter to the given `PlantID`.
3. `DISTINCT` is not necessary unless there is more to your example data and expected results which is not in your post.
4. Also, you would want to make this a parameterized query or stored procedure and pass in the id value so something like: `@plantId INT`, then you would use it in your query instead of your hard coded example.

You're query I think should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  eSMAT_List 
INNER JOIN Organization 
on eSMAT_List.Plant_Id = Organization.mainID
WHERE eSMAT_List.Plant_Id = @plantId (291320 in your example)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ryan Wilson..:)

Comment: So is there a need for me to give `mainID` as foreign key..?

Comment: If `mainID` references `Plant_Id` in table `eSMAT_List` then yes, it would be good to design your table column as a foreign key. Or if it is the other way around where `eSMAT_List` references `Organization` then make `Plant_Id` a foreign key referencing `mainID` - Perhaps this will help (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-foreign-key/). Also, to improve your post, please post your table schema examples as text and not pictures.